# Continously differentiable function in a arbitrary set

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Currently I am studing Partiall differential Equations and Dirichlet problems and I came up with the case where a function $u$ is $C^2$ in the open domain $D$ and $C^1$ in the boundary of $D$ , $\partial{D}$. But how can we say that $u$ is differentiable in a not open set like  $\partial{D}$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same way you would say a function on smooth manifold is differentiable.

Comment: Do you mean that $u$ as $C^1$ in $D$ can be extended to open set containing the $\bar{D}$ ?